# Lookup value is not populating at first place in the picklist field?

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a picklist field named account on the Lead object which populating account value from Account through "Search"(lookup) button from lead. But the value is coming as the first value in the picklist showing "none" as first value and then the account name selected from lookup.

I have replicated the standard behavior of Approve button on the LEAD object.

Can somebody please guide me why it is coming, when I select the account from lookup it should be come as the first value in the picklist field.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?  Not very clear on how everything relates.